# MySQL query Error Code: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'products_stock_location')?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have looked around for an answer but I can't seem to find one.

I am not a mysql database anaylst in any shape or form. Queries are not my strongsuit at all.

I am trying to pull data from multiple tables, I can get most of the data how ever the last bit of data I need to use a different FROM.

Here are the two working queries I want to merge together -

```
USE *database-name*;
SELECT products.products_id, products_with_attributes_stock.sku, products_description.products_name, products.products_model, products_with_attributes_stock.stock_attributes, products.products_price, products.products_cost, products_stock_location.quantity
FROM products, products_stock_location
INNER JOIN products_stock_location ON products.products_id=products_stock_location.products_id
INNER JOIN products_description ON products.products_id=products_description.products_id
INNER JOIN products_with_attributes_stock ON products.products_id=products_with_attributes_stock.products_id;


USE *database-name*;
SELECT stock_location.stock_location_name
FROM products_stock_location
INNER JOIN stock_location ON products_stock_location.stock_locations_id=stock_location.stock_location_id;
```

I have tried this but it gives the 1066 error:

```
USE *database-name*;
SELECT products.products_id, products_with_attributes_stock.sku, products_description.products_name, products.products_model, products_with_attributes_stock.stock_attributes, products.products_price, products.products_cost, products_stock_location.quantity, stock_location.stock_location_name
FROM products, products_stock_location
INNER JOIN products_stock_location ON products.products_id=products_stock_location.products_id
INNER JOIN products_description ON products.products_id=products_description.products_id
INNER JOIN products_with_attributes_stock ON products.products_id=products_with_attributes_stock.products_id
RIGHT JOIN stock_location ON products_stock_location.stock_locations_id=stock_location.stock_location_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the table `products_stock_location` twice in your 'merged' query. Give one of them an alias and use the alias where needed.

**Edit:** I guess the first one can be removed.

Change:

```
FROM products, products_stock_location INNER JOIN products_stock_location ON products.products_id=products_stock_location.products_id
```

Into:

```
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_stock_location ON products.products_id=products_stock_location.products_id
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to figure it out before you replied, but it was this :) thank you